# Sample flex websites for testing

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to test FLex application which is not working, so i would like to test other application which built on Flex GUi to verify whether my application is not supporting or issue with my system.

Please help me in getting sample GUI FLEX application for testing

Comment: This is one of those questions that will probably get closed, quoting the text from the close dialog: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It's been so long, I can't even think of any sites that use Flex. But maybe if you **also** describe the problem you're facing, someone can help you w/the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have some open source projects made with Apache Flex, this one in particular can be helpful for you:

https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/icon-generator